# Point the aws server URL with port to my customed domain name registered with cpanel?

Tags: laravel, redirects

I have a Laravel system hosted on AWS server(just example) - `3.75.56.104:8080`. I also have a registered domain with a direct admin cpanel. How do I point AWS URL to the registered domain. So that when someone types the URL, all resources on AWS server URL stated are accessible on my website domain?

Answer (score 3):

I can assume from your question that you wish to point your domain to the server hosted on the said IP address.

In that case,

1. Log in to the Domain Control Panel.
2. Navigate to the "Manage DNS" or "DNS Zone file" section.
3. Look for A record. There should be only one.
4. Edit it and change its value to 3.75.56.104. Save it.

Now your domain is pointing to your IP address.

I am assuming that you have hosted the Laravel app on some web server like Apache or Nginx. In that case, I am also assuming that you have configured the virtual host entry within these servers because, without this, the domain pointing will not work as expected.

Comment: I have tried this. Am getting this message on the browser - OpenLiteSpeed is functioning normally

Comment: Great. Its working great. Is there a way I can disable or hide the port from the website url?

Comment: If you want to hide the port from the URL you need to run the HTTP server on port 80 rather than 8080.  If you are running an HTTPS server, that would have to run on port 443.    If you are already running some other web server like nginx or Apache on port 80 then you will need to configure it to reverse proxy from port 8080.